# Python3 - How to concatenate dictionaries for GeoJSON?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, geojson

So this might be a really obvious answer but I can't seem to get the hang of it.

I am trying to build a choropleth map of my city. I have the boundaries of different districts in XY coordinates.

I have to match it with the GeoJSON spec to feed into folium. "feature" should be dictionary of JSON features.

```
geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": feature
}
```

To build the features dict, I used:

```
for district in range(len(khobar_districts_xy)):

    feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": khobar_districts_xy[district]["boundaries"]},
            "properties": {
                "district_id": khobar_districts_xy[district]["district_id"],
                "city_id": khobar_districts_xy[district]["city_id"],
                "name_en": khobar_districts_xy[district]["name_en"]}
        }
```

For a single feature this arrangement works, but once I loop it for many districts, it needs to be in the form:

```
{{feature1},{feature2},{feature3}}
```

I have tried a lot of stuff, including writing to a file and reading from it, but I seem to keep running into issues. Does anyone have a good solution?

Full code [here](https://github.com/musaddiqsajjad/Coursera_Capstone/blob/main/The%20Battle%20of%20Neighborhoods%20-%20Coursera%20Capstone%20Project.ipynb)

Comment: It's not clear what the inputs or the desired output should be. Could you please [edit] this into a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "feature" should be dictionary of JSON features.
>
> ```
> geojson = {
>     "type": "FeatureCollection",
>     "features": feature
> }
> ```

I'm pretty sure `features` (note the plural) should be a *list* of dictionaries:

```
[{feature1},{feature2},{feature3}]
```

That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: I tried that, I defined a features dict and tried to add feature dicts to it, but since the key for each dict is the same dict.update() method just updates the same key.

So at the end of the loop I end up with the last feature

Comment: @Musaddiq I said "list of dictionaries", not "dict of dictionaries".